# Load a DetailViewController in TableViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, detailview

I just followed this tutorial:
[Implementing UITableView Sections from an NSArray of NSDictionary Objects](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/)

This is a good example. But I want to add more fonctions. I want to load a `detailView`. I followed more than 5 tutorials to do it, but I fail every time. After 4 hours, i'm asking you.

How can I load a `detailView` with this sample?

Regards, Fanny

---

Already tried, nowi have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *selectedRow = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    selectedRow = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

    //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
    DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    dvController.selectedRow = selectedRow;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];

    [dvController release];
    dvController = nil;
```

But nothing appen :/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this tutorial help you.

http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/uitableview-%E2%80%93-2-loading-a-detail-view/